# vba code to get all combinations if they equal a cell

Tags: vba, excel, combinations, permutation

So I have a 15 column by 100 row sheet of data that has all different percentages, from 100%-0%, that I'm looking to get all possible combinations out of it. Right now I have a code that works that puts the combinations into another 15 columns. The problem is, how do I make the code only output the combinations that when added together = 100%. This is the code that I have right now.

```
Sub Perm()
  Dim rSets As Range, rOut As Range
  Dim vArr As Variant, lRow As Long

  Set rSets = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
  ReDim vArr(1 To rSets.Columns.Count)
  Set rOut = Cells(1, rSets.Columns.Count + 2)
  Perm1 rSets, vArr, rOut, 1, lRow
  End Sub

  Sub Perm1(rSets As Range, ByVal vArr As Variant, rOut As Range, ByVal lSetN As Long, lRow As Long)
  Dim j As Long

  For j = 1 To rSets.Rows.Count
      If rSets(j, lSetN) = "" Then Exit Sub
      vArr(lSetN) = rSets(j, lSetN)
      If lSetN = rSets.Columns.Count Then
          lRow = lRow + 1
          rOut(lRow).Resize(1, rSets.Columns.Count).Value = vArr
      Else
          Perm1 rSets, vArr, rOut, lSetN + 1, lRow
      End If
  Next j
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I assumed your percentages were decimal values and not text (.3 instead of 30%).  Just added an if statement that sum's vArr and checks if the sum is 1.

```
  Sub Perm1(rSets As Range, ByVal vArr As Variant, rOut As Range, ByVal lSetN As Long, lRow As Long)
  Dim j As Long

  For j = 1 To rSets.Rows.Count
      If rSets(j, lSetN) = "" Then Exit Sub
      vArr(lSetN) = rSets(j, lSetN)
      If lSetN = rSets.Columns.Count Then
          If WorksheetFunction.Sum(vArr) = 1 Then
              lRow = lRow + 1
              rOut(lRow).Resize(1, rSets.Columns.Count).Value = vArr
          End If
      Else
          Perm1 rSets, vArr, rOut, lSetN + 1, lRow
      End If
  Next j
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. And yes the percentages are decimal values. Is there anyway to speed this up because it has been running for the past hour and isn't done running yet so I'm not sure if this has worked yet or not?

Comment: I've checked with smaller sets of data, and it does seem to work...however after re-reading your question and seeing the quantity of data you are using, you might need to reconsider the scope.   I'm no mathematician but with this algorithm you are looking at evaluating 100^15 combinations (1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000).

Comment: How long do you think it would take to run to complete it? What other way do you think I can do this?

Comment: Again I'm no mathematician but even at 100 000 combinations a second, with 31 536 000 seconds per year, the runtime will be approximately 317 097 919 837 645 865 years.  My computer was around 20 000 combinations a second with a significantly smaller data set 16 rows 5 columns (1 048 576 combinations). The code you have is defiantly the brute force method.  Not sure what the data is your analyzing, but you may need to review it and see if there are other patterns you can find...  Or Re-scale your scope.. Or invest in a quantum computer (last I heard they were only 15-mil).

Comment: They might have a spare quantum computer for use at your local Rent-A-Center